# Is there any efficient way to convert GeoJSON to WKT?

Tags: postgis, geojson, convert, well-known-text

I want to use `ST_GeomFromText()` to load vector data to PostGIS. However, I don't know how to convert from GeoJSON type to WKT.

N.B. I know I can use OGR2OGR to upload the GeoJSON directly, but I just want to confirm if there is any way to convert it or not.

Comment: ogr2ogr could be a way

Comment: Efficient in what way?

Comment: If your PostGIS version >2, you import GeoJSON directly.

Answer (score 14):

why not use

- [ST_GeomFromGeoJSON](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html)  which takes as input a geojson representation of a geometry and outputs a PostGIS geometry object.
- [ST_AsGeoJSON](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html), the inverse

see [Creating GeoJSON Feature Collections with JSON and PostGIS functions](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/267-Creating-GeoJSON-Feature-Collections-with-JSON-and-PostGIS-functions.html) or 
[ST_GeomFromGeoJSON](http://blog.opengeo.org/2011/11/21/st_geomfromgeojson/) from OpenGeo.

To convert to WKT, use

- [ST_AsText](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsText.html) , the reverse of ST_GeomFromText() which return the Well-Known Text (WKT)
- [ST_AsEWKT](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsEWKT.html) same with SRID meta data

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much. I don't even know this tool. I am still learning from you as a student.

Answer (score 8):

If Python is your thing then you can use [GeoMet](https://github.com/larsbutler/geomet). It's a Python module that converts GeoJSON to WKT/WKB and vice versa. You can install it directly from the github repository using pip

```
$ pip install git+git://github.com/larsbutler/geomet.git
```

Here is a sample conversion:

```
>>> from geomet import wkt
>>> point = {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [116.4, 45.2, 11.1]}
>>> wkt.dumps(point, decimals=4)
'POINT (116.4000 45.2000 11.1000)'
```

Comment: More recent versions can be found in the GeoMet organization: https://github.com/geomet/geomet

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but this question comes up highly when looking for ways to make OGR2OGR output as WKT and no one has specifically answered how to do that:

> As of GDAL/OGR 1.6.0 it is possible to emit WKT in CSV output

```bash
echo 'Your GeoJSON' | ogr2ogr -f CSV -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT /vsistdout/ /vsistdin/
```

[Source](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/3145)